# Install Apache Hue on windows

Tags: hadoop, hue, dbeaver

Is Apache Hue supported in windows.

```
I downloaded the hue 2.1.0 and modified the hue.ini to point to hadoop(psudo-distributed mode).
Modified: In Hadoop and Yarn
hadoop_hdfs_home -> hadoop-2.7.3/lib
hadoop_bin -> hadoop-2.7.3/bin
hadoop_conf_dir -> hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop
webhdfs_url=http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1
```

The Hue doesn't seem to start in localhost:8888.
Does windows supports Hue and if there is anything I need to change?

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I am using Hadoop psuedo distributed clusted on windows 7 and hive 2.1.1 for windows. I was unable to run the hue(since hue is not supported on windows). So decided to use Dbeaver. I could not find the hiveserver2.cmd under hive/bin.

Also not sure which port number to be specified to connect to Apache hive. Is there anything needs to be specified in hive-site.xml for dbeaver?

Comment: Hi Aavik, You can find hadoop ecosystems completely supported for windows platform in the below link.
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/big-data